# Azure API hit returns Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to make an [Azure API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.iresourcegroupsoperations.checkexistencewithhttpmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_IResourceGroupsOperations_CheckExistenceWithHttpMessagesAsync_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_List_System_String___System_Threading_CancellationToken_) where I try to see if a resource exists. I created an Azure app and gave subscription level permission (reader, contributor, backup reader) for my app. But when I hit the API, I get the below error.

> Inner Exception: Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
> at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.ResourceGroupsOperations.d__5.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Below is my code:

```
AzureCredentials azureCredential = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                .FromServicePrincipal(clientId,
                    clientSecret,
                    TenantId,
                    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
RestClient restClient = RestClient
                .Configure()
                .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                .WithCredentials(azureCredential)
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Build();
_resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(restClient);
_resourceManagementClient.SubscriptionId = DSEBackupConstants.SubscriptionId;
Task<bool> resourceGroupTask = Wrapper.checkExistenceAsync(_resourceManagementClient, resourceGroupName);
resourceGroupTask.Wait();
if (resourceGroupTask.Result == false)
{
    return JobResult.FailAndClear("ResourceGroup does not exist");
}
```

Wrapper class

```
public virtual Task<bool> checkExistenceAsync(IResourceManagementClient resourceManagementClient,
                                                      string resourceGroupName)
{
    return resourceManagementClient.ResourceGroups.CheckExistenceAsync(resourceGroupName);
}
```

How can I root cause this issue?

Comment: Did you added some API permissions to you Azure Application (App Registration)?

Comment: The same way you troubleshoot any and all access permission issues: give the user every permission, then remove them one by one until the call fails. But your code is also wonky, you should be using async/await instead of calling Task.Wait() or Task.Result.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I gave the right permission but there was some issue with the app credential. Once I change it, the issue was resolved.